# how to reload external file every time?

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script where my "config" is in an extra file. It's called `ftp_config.rb`. Then I have `filetrack.rb` that downloads files from a ftp server - what files/directories is specified in ftp_config.rb. And finally I got `rufus_download.rb` that is calling a function from filetrack.rb every day so I get all new files from the server.

Everything works fine just I want to know how to make it so when I edit ftp_config.rb the changes are picked up by the script without the need to restart rufus_download.rb.

currenly

- rufus_download.rb contains `require_relative 'filetrack'`
- filetrack.rb contains `require_relative 'ftp_config'`

Right now if I add new files to be downloaded to ftp_config.rb I need to restart rufus

Comment: Hmm... very strange. Just have edited my answer and I can't see your comment. Basically have a look at the updated / edited answer.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I found the answer (load "./ftp_config.rb") when looking around if I have to use load twice or just once. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_relative` returns `false` if the file you have requested is already loaded to your ruby script and returns `true` if you haven't

If you want changes to be loaded directly you need to `load` files

```
load 'path/to/ftp_config'
```

every time your script executes it will load / reload the script

*EDIT:*

you can load by expanding path of the current ruby script:

`load ::File.expand_path('../ftp_config.rb', __FILE__)`

Assuming that files are in the same folder

*EDITEND*

hope that helps

Comment: Could you suggest if using `load 'ftp_config'` is good enough of I need to use `load 'filetrack'` too?

Comment: It depends on your app architechture. From **performance** point of view the file should be relatively easy to load. If you need the app only once per day, then that should be seamless to load both files any time you need the app.

Comment: the question is more if I have to use load twice to get the config reloaded. I do not understand how it works. A function from filetrack.rb is called by rufus and filetrack is using ftp_config.rb.

Comment: The rule of thumb is the code can only rely on the code that has being loaded by interpreter (read MRI, ruby). If you have a dependency A -> B and C -> B. Load A first, then load B then execute the app.

Comment: My understanding is that I want to always load C and the dependency is A (rufus) -> B(file_track) -> C (ftp_config)

Comment: looks like you need to load file_track.rb and ftp_config everytime you run the script. What are you concerns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93624/discussion-between-daniel-myasnikov-and-radek).

Comment: ok, so I needed to use `load` in the function where I want the "ftp_config" to be reloaded each time. I was not good enough to use load at the beginning of `filetrack.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You need a gem that monitors filechanges like "sinatra/reloader" for Sinatra and eg [filewatcher](https://rubygems.org/gems/filewatcher/versions/0.5.2) or [listen](https://rubygems.org/gems/listen/versions/3.0.3) for desktop apps. After detecting an update you `load` the script, not require, that only loads a script once.

Here an example of filewatcher.

```
STDOUT.sync = true

FileWatcher.new(['c:/test/scans']).watch() do |filename, event|
    puts filename
  if(event == :changed)
    puts "File updated: " + filename
  end
  if(event == :delete)
    puts "File deleted: " + filename
  end
  if(event == :new)
    puts "Added file: " + filename
  end
end
```